# How to save button click state in order in android. (Not Toggle Button)

Tags: java, android

Im new to android and I have one problem that bothers me.

I have multiple buttons like the image below 
https://lh4.ggpht.com/ouHPcTcFzsdYrTU09pStGBicxgX_cki613g5Eq3loYCh2TOXzqpfeyWnOdlLuc8eNS0=h900-rw

1.what I want to do is to press 5 buttons in any order.
2.Save the clicked buttons text in order of the clicks.

For Example. I have 1 ~ 31 buttons, and if I press five numbers 1,5,7,8,2

The 5 Buttons that have been clicked will be saved in clicked order.

3.Should I use SharedPreference and ArrayList? I dont want to use toggle button and check box but a simple Button. I'm not sure what kind logic and class I must use. I'm a noob so if possible, a sample will help me learn a lot !

Comment: That depends on how you will use the saved data and for how long you need it. But for that many items, I wouldn't use `SharedPreferences`. Probably an `ArrayList`, DB, or save to a file.

Comment: you can manage state using boolean variables for every button. for button . for order implement List or arrayalist .make sure you add or remove based boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
clickedButtons = new ArrayList<View>();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!v.isSelected()) {
                v.setSelected(true);
                clickedButtons.add(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why should he try that?

Comment: What I want to do is select 5 random numbers out of 31 buttons and  set them in a variable and send them as parameters according to the order of buttons clicked.